# Is there a way to get duplicate values in a column with specific values in another column?

Tags: mysql, sql, select, relational-division

I have an sql table like this:

```
TABLE: Info

ID      |   JOB    |  Value
--------|----------|------------------
1       |   leader |  3
2       |   Host   |  212
1       |   User   | 4
2       |   leader |  5
2       |   Host   |  4
```

I'm trying to get the rows where a duplicate ID must contain 3 and 4 from the Value column.
I'm currently using this  query:

```
  select * from info where value = 3 and 4
   group by id having count(*) > 1;
```

my result using this query

```
ID     |   JOB    |  Value
--------|----------|------------------
null    |   null   |  null
```

whereas my expected result should be:

```
ID      |   JOB    |  Value
--------|----------|------------------
1       |   leader |  3
1       |   User   | 4
```

Please help as I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong

Comment: Syntax Error `where value = 3 and 4` try `where value = 3 and value = 4`

Comment: If you are grouping by `id` then you are not going to get 2 rows with the same `id`

Answer (score 0):

your expected  result sample  is not coherent with your  question description  ..  the duplicated  rows for value 3,4  are selected  using

```
select id
from info
where value in  (3,4)
group by id 
having count(id)>1
```

then

```
select  * 
from  info 
inner join  (
    select id
    from info
    where value in  (3,4)
    group by id 
    having count(id)>1
) t on t.id = info.id
```